# Actionscript3, Adobe Air for mobile: How to put an Image into an IconItemRenderer?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I want to display a list of dynamically generated images. I am trying to use an IconItemRenderer, however, I cannot figure out how to display the image (a spark.components.Image) in the IconItemRenderer.

I have tried the following:
        iir.iconContentLoader = image.contentLoader;

But this did not work. The image is correct, when I use addElement(image) instead, it works.

So, how can I add a dynamic image to an IconItemRenderer?

Comment: Did my answer help you at all or are you still stuck and looking?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the iconFunction property in the iconItemRenderer class as follows:

```
iir.iconFunction = getImage;

...

private function getImage(item:Object):* {
    return image.contentLoader;
}
```